# Why the ADS-B out doesn't broadcast the True air speed in its ES message?

Tags: airspeed, ads-b

The ASTERIX (version 2.1) items of ADS-B GS cat 21 contain True air speed but when we check the Asterix data that we recieved by GS we did not find the True air speed value, why ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you scroll down in [the document](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/2019-06/asterix-cat021-asterix-ads-b-messages-part-12-v1.8-012011.pdf) to the description of true airspeed, it says "This item is optional."

Many aircraft do not have the capability to measure their true airspeed, and it makes no sense to transmit anything if the value is unknown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.but isn't the optional mean it is optional to decoding this items?.also the whole aircraft that I checked transmitted the true Air speed via EHS register ( Radar interrogation)

Comment: @Uniform No, it says that under "encoding rules," not "decoding rules." An aircraft does not need to include true airspeed in an ADS-B message. Even if it is available, an aircraft is not required to transmit it.